# Parsing ISO8601 date/time with DateTime struct

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc, iso8601

I am trying to parse an ISO8601 formatted date/time string with .NET's DateTime structure.

*In order for me to give a full underdstanding of the problem, I am going to perform tests using both .NET and JavaScript. I am currently in Britain (British Summer Time, which is UTC+01:00).*

My understanding of ISO8601 is that:

- When the string is suffixed with "Z", the time is expressed in UTC.
- When the string is suffixed with "+/-hh:mm", the time is expressed in
  Local time, where the "+/-hh:mm" expresses the offset from UTC.

**Consider the following ISO8601 date/time format string:**

```
"1987-01-05T08:45:30.500+0100"
```

Given my points above, this string expresses a local time of "08:45:30", and a UTC time of "07:45:30"

**Current TimeZone Test (.NET)**

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToLocalTime()); // 27/08/2013 12:02:43
Console.WriteLine(now.ToUniversalTime()); // 27/08/2013 11:02:43
```

**Current TimeZone Test (JavaScript)**

```
var now = new Date(Date.now());
now.toString(); // Tue Aug 27 2013 12:03:46 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
now.toUTCString(); // Tue, 27 Aug 2013 11:03:46 GMT
```

Aside from the minor (minute/second) differences between the two examples, they are returning exactly what I would expect for British Summer Time (UTC+01:00). *The minute/second differences are because I can't run both a .NET test and a JavaScript test at EXACTLY the same time.*

So now lets use my ISO8601 date/time formatted string:

**Parsing ISO8601 Format String (.NET)**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("1987-01-05T08:45:30.500+0100");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLocalTime()); // 05/01/1987 07:45:30
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime()); // 05/01/1987 07:45:30
```

**Parsing ISO8601 Format String (JavaScript)**

```
var dt = new Date("1987-01-05T08:45:30.500+0100");
dt.toString(); // Mon Jan 05 1987 07:45:30 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
dt.toUTCString(); //Mon, 05 Jan 1987 07:45:30 GMT
```

This does not seem consistent with the example which displays the date/time "**now**". Why is this displaying as though I am in British Winter time (UTC+00:00), when the "now" examples display in British Summer Time (UTC+01:00)?

If I change my time zone settings, I get the expected results for Local/Universal time, but if they are set to my current time/zone, this seems to give inconsisteent results.

**Edit:** In short, it's as if both .NET and JavaScript are ignoring daylight saving/british summer time (UTC+01:00) when I try to parse the string. The result would be correct for winter, and also correct when I physically change my time/zone...but as is stands this is not correct on "**any**" machine I have tested on in Britain.

Comment: I think the `+0100` is ignored, it may depend on `Regional settings` on the local computer. I've tested the code and it showed me `07:45:30` vs `02:45:30` not as in your test.

Comment: This is what you get for living/coding in UTC timezone... Parse *always* return local time, but in your case to UTC and to local are no-op.

Comment: In fact your code should result as `Local: 05/01/1987 07:45:30` and `UTC: 05/01/1987 08:45:30`, `+0100` is just to specify that the time is `UTC`, so all the local time will be `UTC time - 1`.

Comment: @series0ne I have to say that your example works OK for me (on my machine), in fact the `+0100` means that the actual `Local time` is 1 hour **less than** than the `UTC time` (not greater than as you thought). It just to indicate the `time string` is `UTC`.

Comment: @KingKing, it seems that every machine I've tested ignores daylight saving. Ordinarily the UK is UTC+00:00, but it's UTC+01:00 in summer. Therefore when I parse the ISO8601 string, it parses it as it it's winter (hence UTC and local time appear the same).

Answer (score 2):

Britain uses ***summer time*** (advancing their clocks by one hour) in the summer (27 August, your "now" in the examples), but not in the winter (5 January, from your parsing of "1987-***01-05***T08:45:30.500+0100").

Actually, in the winter Britain uses UTC. Your machine seems to have a British `TimeZoneInfo`. You can check with `TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName` (since .NET 3.5) or `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName` (old).

You can check with `dt.IsDaylightSavingTime()`.

*Addition:*

My answer is about .NET only (but maybe the same applies to JavaScript?). The examples you provide work entirely as expected. A date and time in January 1987 will be converted into your local zone, which is supposedly British, and in January 1987 the United Kingdom was at +0000 since it was winter. The time string you gave was stamped with +0100 (as if it was from Germany or some other country one hour to the east of Britain), and this was acknowledged when the string was parsed. A date in the summer of 1987 would correctly have converted differently because in the summer of 1987 Britain (and all of the EEC) observed summer time (daylight saving time).

To sum up: The offset indicator or zone specifier `+0100` *is* considered when interpreting the time. This is converted into British time on your computer. If you want conversion to UTC instead of conversion to the local time of your machine, use the overload that takes a `DateTimeStyles` enum and include the flag `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`.

If you want a value that better represents time *and* absolute zone, consider using the struct `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. You can also consider NODA time instead of the .NET types.

Comment: That is correct. I've eventually worked out that the point I'm trying to make is that neither .NET, nor JavaScript seem to preserve the offset. Therefore, you always get a UTC time back. I guess the reason for this is that if the offset was preserved, it would be inconsistent with a users machine. i.e. if the offset was +0100 and the users timezone was +0800, the offset (local/time) would not be consistent on the users machine...if that makes sense?

Comment: @series0ne I think you are wrong. Please try to change the string `"1987-01-05T08:45:30.500+0100"` into e.g. `"1987-07-05T08:45:30.500+0100"` (summer). ***Edit:*** Also, for less confusion, try with a string with a zone that is far from Britain, like `+1100` or something. The zone _is_ considered.

Comment: I've edited the entire question, would you mind taking another look? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ToLocalTime and ToUniversalTime do take into account Daylight saving time and do a very good job at it. At least in .Net, the Javascript Date object has flaws and I would recommend using moment.js and moment-timezone.js for conversions in js.

Here is my unit test and the results:

```
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(now.ToLocalTime());
        Console.WriteLine(now.ToUniversalTime());

        //Test 1 TimeZone UTC+1 London, etc..
        //current day 20th July = BST

        /*  07/20/2015 01:06:43
            07/20/2015 00:06:43*/

        //set day to 20th Januray UK winter time

        /*  01/20/2015 01:07:55
            01/20/2015 01:07:55*/
```

For you to get the results described above in .Net you would need to a) set the time zone to UTC+2 b) run into a glitch in the ToLocalTime() which has since be fixed, MSDN mentions flaws on XP when converting dates.

Finally DateTime.Now returns the local time so using DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() is a bit redundant and you may well get unexpected results.