# .NET/JavaScript ignores daylight saving (DST) when parsing ISO8601

Tags: javascript, .net, datetime, utc, dst

I have been testing date/time parsing using .NET and JavaScript. This questing is linked to this one that I asked previously:

[Parsing ISO8601 date/time with DateTime struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454631/parsing-iso8601-date-time-with-datetime-struct)

*Please note that the examples here are .NET. To get an example of this issue in JavaScript too,  see the link above.*

It appears that when parsing an ISO8601 format date/time, it ignores DST (daylight saving):

**Example:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Inspecting DateTime.Now");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToLocalTime());
Console.WriteLine(now.ToUniversalTime());

Console.WriteLine("Inspecting ISO8601 Parsing");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("1987-01-05T08:45:30.500+0100");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLocalTime());
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToUniversalTime());
```

**Results:**

```
//  Inspecting DateTime.Now
//  27/08/2013 13:44:33
//  27/08/2013 12:44:33

//  Inspecting ISO8601 Parsing
//  05/01/1987 07:45:30
//  05/01/1987 07:45:30
```

When I display local/universal time for DateTime.Now, this is correct. Britain is currently in DST (Daylight Saving Time, UTC+01:00).

When I display local/universal time for the ISO8601 string, this is incorrect, both are displaying UTC time. Local time should be "05/01/1987 08:45:30"

This issue occurs with JavaScript too.

If I change my time zone to something else (i.e. UTC+04:00), then I get the expected (correct) results, but with my current settings it seems to ignore DST (Daylight Saving Time).

**Note:** UK time zone **IS** UTC+00:00, but DST puts us in UTC+01:00...it's the latter that seems to be being ignored when parsing the date/time.

Any ideas why, or how to fix this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with ecma javascript?

Comment: @HMR, see the link to my previous question. JavaScript also ignores BST/DST daylight saving. It assumes that I am in UTC+00:00 when parsing, but due to BST/DST it should be UTC+01:00 ... The example here is written with .NET, but broadly applies to JavaScript too.

Comment: Has the JS part not already been answered by Jeppe? It seems that if you use a date like 1987-01-05 +01:00 you have a date `1987-01-05` where UTC+1 is used (Amsterdam/Paris/Berlin) but then you toString it so it's converted to your timezone (one hour earlier). The JS timezone works as expected doesn't it?

Comment: @HMR, Nope...as I've stated; JavaScript and .NET ignore DST. If you change the time zone manually, then you get the correct result.

Comment: What is the expected output? JavaScript can only create date strings that are GMT or your local settings. If your local settings are UK then a  GMT+0800 (China) will be converted to UK time when you toString() it or to GMT when you toGMTString it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times `The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z", "22:30+04"` `add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset.` Zulu plus one in winter is the time used in Amsterdam/Paris/Berlin so it's one hour ahead of your local time isn't it?

Comment: @HMR, that's not the issue. The parser is parsing the date/time correctly, HOWEVER, say I do it in Britain in winter (UTC+00:00)...Both UTC and Local time are the same. If I do it in summer, Britain is still UTC+00:00 BUT becuase of DST, we move to UTC+01:00...This is being ignored, and it only ever parses as UTC+00:00

Comment: @HMR, If you look at the results here, you'll see what I mean. DateTime.Now knows about DST, therefore Local time is 13:44, whereas UTC is 12:44. When parsing ISO8601, both times are 07:45, hoewever local time should be 08:45 (taking into account DST)...but this is not happening.

Comment: GMT and your timezone are not the same thing. GMT does not use Daylight saving time so 8:00 GMT in winter is 9:00 UK but 8:00 GMT summer is 8:00 UK if you use hh:mm:ss+01:00 then Zulu time is expected. Zulu = GMT = UTC so an offset can be expected depending on the season.

Comment: "1987-01-05T08:45:30.500+0100" is Mon Jan 05 1987 so no DST that's why the GMT and local time are the same for your timezone. The +01:00 puts the time in Amsterdam/Paris/Berlin and when it was 8:45 in Amsterdam on Jan 5 1987 it was 7:45 in London and and GMT was 7:45

Comment: @HMR...I think it's just clicked! 05/01/1987 was in January (obv), so in the UK, that was UTC+00:00...DST for the UK in January is UTC+00:00... *FACEPALM* :-/

Comment: @HMR, Perhaps I should have tested with a few other dates than my dob. It might have been clearer then!